# Issue with H2 migration from WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am making migration from WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to 5.0.0, and one of steps is to get registry from 4.8.1. In my case, my registry is in a H2 database, the database by default.

I followed migration guide from WSO2 but I get "File corrupted ..." error in server up.

I would like to avoid make migration manually.

Can anyone know the steps to achieve the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got to do migration with following steps:

1. Download h2database jar file (for example, from maven central).
2. Run the jar: `java -jar h2-1.X.YYY.jar` (Depends on version). H2 Console will start in `http://localhost:8082`.
3. Set JDBC URL: `jdbc:h2:/<absolute_path_to_wso2_home>/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB`.
4. Use the following credential: `wso2carbon:wso2carbon`.
5. Execute: `ALTER TABLE 'REG_RESOURCE' MODIFY REG_CREATED_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;` and `ALTER TABLE 'REG_RESOURCE' MODIFY REG_LAST_UPDATED_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;`
6. Finally, copy from `<ESB_HOME_4.8.1>/repository/database/WSOCARBON_DB.h2.db` and `<ESB_HOME_4.8.1>/repository/database/WSOCARBON_DB.h2.db/WSO2CARBON_DB.lobs.db/` to `<ESB_HOME_5.0.0>/repository/database/`.